# Improving "the question is if A is B or C"

Tags: expressions, writing

> The next question is if X is a regulation based on subjective
>   condition or a regulation based on objective condition.

I wrote the sentence like the above in my research paper.

A basic structure of the sentence is **'the question is if A is B or C'**

I'm concerned if my sentence is too 'simple'.

I want to make my sentence more elegant

Is there any way to express it (the question is if A is B or C') in other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegance for the sake of elegance is generally deprecated in academic style, and simplicity is regarded as a virtue.

However, the sentence can be made easier to parse:

- *if* may lead a reader to expect a conditional construction, and then have to adjust her interpretation when she discovers it has a different sense. Replace *if* with *whether*.
- *if/whether X is a regulation ...* may lead her to expect that the question is whether X is or is not a regulation; and (again) have to adjust her interpretation. There appears in fact to be **no** question that X is a regulation, so move *regulation*, and eliminate its repetition:

  > The question is whether regulation X is based on a subjective or an objective condition.

Much simpler, and much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your sentence is "too simple," but I do think it's a little awkward and can be improved.

You could cut most of the introductory words and be more direct:

> *Furthermore, is X a regulation based on subjective conditions, or on objective conditions?*

I think the culprit here is your first *is*:

> The next question is...

Consider:

- One way to improve your writing is to restructure sentences that are built around the word "is".
- You can improve your writing by restructuring sentences that are built around the word "is".

See what I did there?